# Обособление запятыми "поэтому"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли обособлять слово "поэтому" запятыми? (Ещё я не уверен, что перед словом "начиная" нужна запятая.)

"В последних Перспективах мировой экономики МВФ, поэтому, ожидает, что, хотя Омикрон будет давить на деловую активность в I квартале этого года, данный эффект начнёт меркнуть, начиная со II квартала."

"Перспективы мировой экономики" - это ежеквартальный прогноз, который делает МВФ (Международный валютный фонд).

Comment: тут, вообще все не на русском языке написано